# Committee of three

Tags: probability

Committee of three is randomly selected from six people, denoted a,b,c,d,e and f. Consider two events
A: both a and b are on the committee
and B: neither c nor d are on the committee.
a) compute P(A), b) Compute P(A|B), c) Are A and B independent? Explain your answer

I am trying to do a. for P(A) I get 5C2= 10. but when I count it individually it comes up to 16/120

Comment: So,... what have you tried?

Comment: well I cant get past the first step, the answer I am getting for a is 5C2= 10. but when I count it individually it comes up to 16

Comment: $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ is not a probability....

Comment: no clue how to go about it, when i count it individually its 16/120

Answer (score 1):

We note that there are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ was to choose a committee of $3$ from $6$.

Event A: If both $a$ and $b$ are on the the same committee, then there are $\binom{6-2}{1} = \binom{4}{1} = 4$ ways to make a committee. Thus, 
$$P(A) = 4/20 $$

Event B: If neither $c$, nor $d$ is on the committee, they cannot both individually be on the committee, or together on the committee. We note that there are $\binom{6-1}{2} = \binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to pick a committee with $c$, likewise $d$ on it, however this over-counts. In particular, we have over counted the number of committee which have both $c$, and $d$ on them. But, we have already counted this in event A. Thus, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2} - \binom{4}{1} = 10 - 4 = 6$$ committee which have just $c$ on them.

This should be more than enough to finish the problem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) for addition resources.

Comment: thanks, so for P(B) it will be,  4C3 = 4 and since there are 20 ways to form a committee of 3. P(B)=4/20
is that correct?

Comment: No. $P(B)$ is the probability that a committee does not have, ($d$), nor ($c$) nor ($d$ and $c$).